# Setup of React Native using ndenv on OS X

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native

I'm running into PATH difficulty setting up a new React Native iOS project in Xcode 7.1.  I'm trying to use [`ndenv`](https://github.com/riywo/ndenv) to manage node versions, which means `~/.ndenv/shims` needs to be on PATH.  To that end, I have PATH set as a user-defined project setting as `$PATH:~/.ndenv/shims`.  The Xcode settings UI shows the correct expanded PATH value.

Yet the project, generated by `react-native init`, still fails to build.  The custom build script fails to find `react-native`:

`../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh: line 36: react-native: command not found`

`react-native` is installed correctly, but the environment variables dump in the build output makes clear that `~/.ndenv/shims` isn't on PATH.  My PATH settings don't appear in the build environment.  However, if I set a random user-defined setting (e.g. `FOOBAR=baz`), that *does* correctly show up in the build environment.

That result plus further inspection of PATH in the build environment makes clear that Xcode is overriding PATH somewhere along the line.

So in order of preference:

- How do I correctly append to PATH for a custom build script in Xcode 7?
- Alternatively, what's the best (least hacky?) way of getting ndenv-managed npm modules on PATH for the build script?

Modifying react-native-xcode.sh is out of the question, since that's a part of the external react-native npm module.

**UPDATE 1**

As a temporary workaround, I've bailed on ndenv and installed node via homebrew.  This puts `react-native` on the (apparently-hardcoded) Xcode path at `/usr/local/bin`, and works to get the build running.  I'm not going to submit or accept this as a solution, since it doesn't allow the repeatable control of node versions that ndenv does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was effectively fixed when [facebook/react-native#5518](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/5518) landed.  `react-native-xcode.sh` now respects a NODE_BINARY environment variable that tells it where to find `node` on the build system.  Under your app's target, see Build Phases > Bundle React Native code and images and set the shell script code to:

```
export NODE_BINARY=$HOME/.ndenv/shims/node
../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh
```

If your `node` is in a different location, change the value of NODE_BINARY to suit your installation.  Here's a screencap from Xcode 7.1 to aid navigation:

[image: Set NODE_BINARY under "Bundle React Native code and images"]

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the `react-native-xcode.sh` script depends on the `react-native-cli` package to be in PATH. This issue was reported to the project in these two issues on Github:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3974
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3948

I expect a fix to be implemented quite soon, because this is a major problem for anyone using the react-native cli to create new projects.

There are a few work arounds for this problem, but none of them are perfect. Which one would work for you depends on your node / npm setup:

I myself installed node via nvm and just needed to add `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`before running the `react-native-xcode.sh`.
For this to work you need to have `react-native-cli` installed globally.

If you need help finding a solution for your specific setup, please give me some more information about your node setup. ( or you can try one of the other solutions pointed out in the issues I linked above. )

Comment: I'm using node via ndenv, linked above, which I prefer to the nvm/rvm system.  rvm established the pattern of managing versions via shell functions, meaning that it's literally unusable without a shell running the rvm runtime.  rbenv/ndenv instead just maintain a directory of scripts (`~/.ndenv/shims`), placed on PATH.  For node, npm, and any node bin script, there's a matching script in the shim dir. E.g. when `react-native` is run, the shim asks ndenv which node to use then invokes the original script using that version. No special shell setup required, just one dir on PATH makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.  The work around called out in the link below is working for me.  Haven't found a permanent solution.

*The XCode $PATH differs from terminal $PATH and it doesn't include path of nvm nodes (~/.nvm/versions/...). This can be temporarily fixed by adding source ~/.bash_profile to the beginig of react-native-xcode.sh*

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3948

Comment: Great, thanks for the link to that issue. That hadn't come up in my searches so far for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a fix for this was just published as release 0.14.2

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.14.2

Comment: Thanks.  I'd noticed that, and nvm users should definitely upgrade. Unfortunately the fix is hardcoded and exclusive to nvm, because there are a ton of React Native users using nvm.  nvm works by injecting functions into the shell to proxy to the current node version for each npm binstub. Thus it's literally impossible to set PATH to interoperate with nvm, making it terrible for automation.  Sadly, 0.14.2's nvm fix is useless to ndenv users, homebrew installed outside of `/usr/local`, or other node version management tools.  I'm still resorting to my "Update 1" solution, above.