# react-native init causing build fail out of box

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native

Using `react-native init <projectName>`, then `npm install` results in a build fail with error :

```
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127
```

and message:

```
 ../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh: line 36: react-native: command not found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127
```

Have installed react-native both locally, and globally to no avail.

Has anyone run into this issue and know how to solve?

Comment: I think you have the same problem as described in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588598/setup-of-react-native-using-ndenv-on-os-x/33598753#33598753

Comment: make sure you're using the latest version of all dependencies as well, particularly node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hack explained here works:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3948

Add `source ~/.bash_profile`
to the beginning of `react-native-xcode.sh`

Apparently, fixed in `0.16.0-rc` !
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/9a64f17de84e50a4fc60f1b96168aa61925934a8